# Knockout mapping plugin trouble getting binding properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to understand knockout in combination with the knockout mapping plugin.

I've an asp.net MVC application returning a model (an array of customers).

My controller:

```
Public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>{
         .....initializing-code for the customerlist

         };
    return View(customers);
}
```

in my View i have a script as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
    };

    var myViewModel;

    $(function() {
        var jsonModel = '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model, new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter()))';
        myViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonModel, {}, new ViewModel());
        ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
    });

</script>
```

I wanna make a controlflow binding using a foreach......whats the variable name for this foreach binding. I tried '$data' but that doesn't seem to work.

kind regards

Relevant view Code:

```
<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: customers">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <span data-bind="text: FirstName"></span>&nbsp;<span data-bind="text: LastName"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <span data-bind="text: ContactStreet"></span>&nbsp;<span data-bind="text: ContactBuildingNumber"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <span data-bind="text: ContactPostalCode"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <span data-bind="text: ContactCity"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</div>
```

```
@section scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;


    };

    var myViewModel = {};

    $(function() {
        var jsonModel = '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model, new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter()))';
        myViewModel.customers = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonModel, {}, new ViewModel());
        ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have it, you can bind to it like this

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $root">
    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span> 
    ... etc ...
</div>
```

**BUT**, I would do it like this

```
var myViewModel = {};

$(function() {
    var jsonModel = '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model, new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter()))';
    myViewModel.customers = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonModel);
    ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
});
```

Then you can put in your markup

```
<div data-bind="foreach: customers">
    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span> 
    ... etc ...
</div>
```

Because now you can add more properties to your viewmodel, which you surely will need.

**UPDATE**: [Here's a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUU6D/4/). Remember the call is `fromJS`, not `fromJSON`.

Comment: I tried your answer which seems logical. But same problem arisses as with using 'foreach: $data' binding. I shall post full view code. Maybe a typo?

Comment: by the way: no console errors (using chrome development tools)

Comment: OK, I was a little worried there :). Somebody else did it. I updated the "BUT" section of my answer. You dont need a ViewModel constructor pattern, just let ko create the mapped viewmodel.

Comment: If that doesnt work we need to go to jsfiddle, can you put it on jsfiddle? I will get it working

Comment: didn't worked with jsfiddle very much so hopefully i did it the right way: http://jsfiddle.net/Speedy7912/ZUU6D/2/ (update 2 includes jquery)

Comment: In a meeting but I will look in a bit

Comment: Saw your solution. Post the answer and I shall acknowledge it. Question with the answer, for multiple properties as sugested with your current answer, is it possible to have multiple constructors with javascript/knockout?

Comment: OK good pointed, I updated the answer. You can still have one constructor, just pass multiple parameters in to it.

Comment: Trouble with above problem is a result of the new version 3 of knockout. The FromJson overload doesn't seem to exist anymore!!